# Calling C# event using ajax is not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, webmethod

On `Button` click event i have used an `ajax` method, which calls webmethod which is written in server side.

I want to call that method whenever I click the button. But with my current code, it is not hitting the `[WebMethod]` which is written on server side.

Here is both the code

**Ajax code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnAttachParty').click(function () {                
            $.ajax({
                url: 'FrmAgreementMaster.aspx/btnAttachParty_Click?id=' + $(this).attr('id')
            });
        });
    });
```

**Server side code**

```
[WebMethod]
public void btnAttachParty_Click(int id)
{
    if (strMode == "A")
    {
        if (HidAttachVal.Value == "")
        {
            ObjPriCon.Open();
            OracleCommand objpricmd = new OracleCommand("select xxcus.xxacl_pn_party_info_SEQ.nextval from dual", ObjPriCon);
            HidAttachVal.Value = Convert.ToString(objpricmd.ExecuteOracleScalar());
            ObjPriCon.Close();
        }
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", "AttachmentCallParty(" + HidAttachVal.Value + ");", true);
    }
    else
    {
        if (HidAttachVal.Value == "")
        {
            ObjPriCon.Open();
            OracleCommand ObjPriCmd = new OracleCommand("select xxcus.xxacl_pn_party_info_SEQ.nextval from dual", ObjPriCon);
            HidAttachVal.Value = Convert.ToString(ObjPriCmd.ExecuteOracleScalar());
            ObjPriCon.Close();
        }
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", "AttachmentCallParty(" + HidAttachVal.Value + ");", true);
    }
}
```

Kindly let me know why it is not hitting the web method part.

Answer (score 0):

Your `WebMethod` in ASPX **must** be `static`.

```
[WebMethod]
public static void btnAttachParty_Click(int id)
{

}
```

Comment: If I add `static` word, my variable starts giving error

Comment: @nad so debug your error and see what is it. Also I advice you to transfer parameters of the function in the data property of the ajax !

Comment: for `strMode` it is giving error as **An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property**

Comment: So what is strMode define it as static.

Comment: I have already defined that and I m just checking some condition here, I cant define it static again.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is here,

```
$(this).attr('id') // btnAttachParty
```

this will return the id of button.

Try `value` attribute instead of `id`.